# How to import multiple csv files to MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, csv

I have a directory with a bunch of CSV files, I want to import them all to MongoDB and then delete all of them.

On Ubuntu 14.04, the following would work:

```
for f in /home/v/scr/alerts/*; 
do 
    mongoimport -d emails -c main --type csv --file "$f" --headerline && rm /home/v/scr/alerts/*;  
done
```

However, I receive the following output now (on Ubuntu 16.04):

```
2018-01-29T21:49:00.752+0000    connected to: localhost
2018-01-29T21:49:00.759+0000    imported 1 document
2018-01-29T21:49:00.767+0000    Failed: open /home/v/scr/alerts/fH88Vaxr.csv: no such file or directory
2018-01-29T21:49:00.767+0000    imported 0 documents
2018-01-29T21:49:00.772+0000    Failed: open /home/v/scr/alerts/m45EkP9N.csv: no such file or directory
2018-01-29T21:49:00.772+0000    imported 0 documents
```

It appears that the first CSV file is imported correctly, then everything is removed which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

after first import you are removing all files in from the source directory

delete only the file has been imported

```
for f in /home/v/scr/alerts/*; 
do 
    mongoimport -d emails -c main --type csv --file "$f" --headerline
    rm $f #rm only current file
done
```

or delete all source files after successfully imported

```
for f in /home/v/scr/alerts/*; 
do 
    mongoimport -d emails -c main --type csv --file "$f" --headerline
done    
rm /home/v/scr/alerts/* #rm all files
```

optionally we can include isFile check as well

```
if [ -f $f ]; then 
    # import 
fi
```